# STXXL equivalent in C#

Tags: c#

I'm working on extra large datasets that do not fit in memory. I noticed that there exist a library in c++ for out-of-memory computations, known as [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net). I was wondering if there exist any equivalent for C# since most of data manipulation codes are in C#.

Comment: Do you care about what kind of license it has? how about pricing?

Comment: Yes I do, I wanna use it for research purpose only; hence I would rather prefer a free library. But is there any paid library ?